# How can I sort a column with associeted tables inside the cells [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have an excel table with associated tables inside cells. This is an example:

[image]

If you click on "+", you can see the associated table:

[image]

I tried to sort the column PSM from highest to lowest. The problem is that excel doesn't respect the associated column and this one is sorted as well.

That is to say, what I would like to have is a sort rows by PSM where each row has its associated table.
One example of this table can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ccw6-eDhm33Elob7HMJUleDEYHZk_nEd/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is probably offtopic for Stackoverflow. Try https://superuser.com

Comment: This might be more easily done during table creation

Comment: That table is created by a program. I cannot change the options @RonRosenfeld

Comment: In that case, I don't know any method of doing this without using VBA to take the table apart; sort it how you want; then put it back together again.